# buildah run vs buildah unshare: what's the difference?

Tags: buildah

What is the difference between the buildah subcommand `run` and `unshare`? The documentation doesn't exactly say how `buildah unshare` is modifying the user namespace? And I'm confused what exaclty that means.

`buildah help run`

> Runs a specified command using the container's root filesystem as a root filesystem, using configuration settings inherited from the container's image or as specified using previous calls to the config command.

`buildah help unshare`

> Runs a command in a modified user namespace.

Answer (score 2):

`buildah run` executes a command inside of a container on the image.  Similar to the RUN command inside of a Dockerfile.

`buildah unshare` sets up the default user namespace for doing builds, but does not do anything with containers or images.  When you are in `buildah unshare` you are just a normal process on your homedir.  Not in a container.